# Как сделать высоту див-блока автоматически сжимающейся?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы нижний див автоматически уменьшался по высоте, если количество пунктом
меню увеличивается, и увеличивался, если пункты удаляются?

Нужно, чтобы нижний див был по длине от последнего пункта меню, и до нижней белой линии (границы).

[Изображение](http://s017.radikal.ru/i414/1211/77/a00413ee7073.jpg).

Comment: условия/циклы/арифметика - это работа js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не ну как вариант - таблица

```
<style type="text/css">
  table.menu { width: 200px; height: 200px; border-spacing: 5px; }
  table.menu td { background: #666; }
  table.menu td.link { height: 25px; }
</style>
<table class="menu">
  <tr><td class="link">text</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="link">text</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="link">text</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="link">text</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

[image: результат]

Еще вариант, мб вам покажется более адекватным

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.menu { width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden; }
  div.menu div { margin: 2px; padding: 3px; background: #666; }
  div.menu div.bottom { height: 200px; }
</style>
<div class="menu">
  <div>text</div>
  <div>text</div>
  <div>text</div>
  <div>text</div>
  <div>text</div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

[image: результат 2]

Comment: Обновил, дивы